# Position div at the bottom of the page with CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I found no answers before posting on this forum.

I need to position a footer at the bottom of the page, but I need it to be flexible enough to be pushed down by content, if there's enough to spill over the fold.

I've tried the following and it does position it where I need it, however it overlaps the content, which goes underneath.

```
footer {
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0
}
```

I can fix it with jQuery by calculating all div height above the footer, but I was wondering if there's a way to accomplish it with CSS only.

Comment: Do you know the height of your footer? If so, you could add appropriate `padding-bottom` to your content `div` to prevent that overlap.

Comment: search with the term `sticky footer`

Comment: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: So, you want it at the bottom of the window unless the page is longer than the window???

Comment: @j08691 Unfortunately I can not make footer fixed height...

Comment: @Sachin Same problem. I can't make #push the same height as the footer as I don't know the height os footer.

Comment: If you can't guess the footer height, you could just set its negative margin dynamicly with javascript. But the "sticky footer" model is what you want.

Comment: @Brewal Yes, I feel that JS solution is the easiest for this.

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/  is another working example

Answer (score 1):

You will want to change the `position`: `fixed` to `relative`.

I made a jsfiddle to help you see how it'll work.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/QAyab/1/)

[jsfiddle above the fold](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/QAyab/2/)

I am not a god at jquery/javascript at all but I found this helpful link to find a browsers max height. You would use this code to find the height of the browser and then, my best guess, would be an if statement. If `footer` or `div` is above this height then do `.css('position', 'absolute');`

[browser height](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/)

This also just popped into my head from when I was working on my portfolio. If you don't have a set height for your footer then you should just add the same `background` to `html` tag in `CSS`

```
html {
   background: #ff7200;
}

footer{
   background: #ff7200;
}
```

[html footer jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/QAyab/5/)

[my portfolio](http://jpowell43.mydevryportfolio.com/CleanPortfolio/) (If you look at the portfolio, go into the console and delete some of the tabsM off my homepage to see how it works.)

This effect will fill any white space that is after the `footer` or last element in the `body` tag. I think this may be exactly what you want since you don't have a set height.

Comment: If the content is less high than the window, the footer won't be placed at the bottom

Comment: Then to achieve this you will need to use some jquery to check screen size and if content is less then max screen height change position to `absolute`. See fiddle

Comment: Thanks mate, I will try and write some jquery up for you on the second fiddle but for now they show how the change will work.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            Your website content here.
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            Footer goes here
        </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0;
}
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -4em; //negative margin must be the same as your footer/push height
}
.footer, .push {
height: 4em; //height of your footer
}
```

More detailed explanation available here:

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

EDIT: Fiddle with dynamic height calculation using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/KyVpc/

Comment: This "sticky footer" solution has same problem. I can't make #push the same height as the footer as I don't know the height of the footer.

Comment: In that case, check out my fiddle, it gets the height of the footer and fills in the values accordingly using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/KyVpc/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the **[Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)** model as is it what you **almost** need.

The thing is that *you can't predict your footer height*. Well, you will need to use this small piece of jQuery code on **DOM ready** :

```
var footer = $("#footer");
var footerHeight = footer.outerHeight();
footer.css('margin-top', '-'+footerHeight+'px');

var main = $("#main");
main.css('padding-bottom', footerHeight+'px');
```

What is simply does is to change dynamically the negative `margin-top` of the `#footer` and the `padding-bottom` of the `#main` corresponding to the `#footer` height.

**[The Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/duCZx/2/)**